# Why does the function call work even though it is not defined before the call?

Tags: c, forward-declaration, function-declaration

I have done [this quiz](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-language-2-gq/functions-gq/), and do not understand the output

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void demo();
    void (*fun)();
    fun = demo;
    (*fun)();
    fun();
    return 0;
}

void demo()
{
    printf("GeeksQuiz ");
}
```

Expected: Compiler error because I thought that normally `demo()` would need to be initialized before the call in `main()`?

Actual results: `GeeksQuiz GeeksQuiz`

Is my assumption wrong that functions generally need to be defined before they can be called?

Comment: In C an empty parameter list should be indicate by `void`, like `main(void)`.

Answer (score 6):

> *functions generally need to be defined before they can be called*

Well, not actually, compiler just needs to see a prototype before the call (usage). A [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) would be enough.

In your case, inside `main()`,

```
void demo();
```

is serving that purpose. Note that, this is **not** a function call.

Comment: would be beneficial to add that in C, if a function is called before its declaration, the compiler assumes return type of the function as `int`.

Comment: @UlugToprak not since C99, I think. It's obsolete.